# Beautifulsoup handle incorrect xml nesting

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse incorrect xml code with BeautifulSoup as such:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(myXML, "xml")
```

The `myXML`code looks something like this:

```
<body> text <a> more text <b> text </a> why do people do this </b> text </body>
```

Which I would really like to parse as such: (I noticed Google Chrome fixes things in this way)

```
<body> text <a> more text <b> text </b></a><b> why do people do this </b> text </body>
```

But BeautifulSoup switches the tags to the following:

```
<body> text <a> more text <b> text </b> why do people do this </a> text </body>
```

Is there a setting in BeautifulSoup to fix this? Or should I use a different parser that can handle this (if so, which)?

Comment: What parser are you using to do this (BeatifulSoup uses pluggable parser backends, the default is the stdlib html.parser option, or lxml if you have it installed)? It looks like you have *HTML*, by the way.

Comment: And broken HTML is broken HTML; how a parser deals with that is up to the parser.

Comment: I'm using the lxml parser with it, and it's xml with a lot of html-like tags

Comment: The only parser that gets close to what you want is  *html5lib* `BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but with the added caveat that that's a HTML parser. That means tags are parsed case-insensitively, for starters.

Comment: @Swier: right, then you are stuck with this output. Where the HTML standard asks parsers to be tolerant of broken syntax and gives some guidelines on how to handle such broken HTML, the XML standard has no such requirements or guidelines. XML should really only be parsed when valid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the `xml` and `lxml` parser seem to have slightly different behaviour which I might be able to abuse to hack my way to some sort of solution. Thanks for the feedback! (And yeah, I agree on valid XML part)

Comment: @Swier: `lxml` is the *HTML parser*; `lxml-xml` or `xml` is the XML parser. So yes, the behaviour will be different, because HTML is parsed differently.